# Algebraic number theory proof question

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, finitely-generated, algebraic-integers

Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n$ and let $H$ be a finitely generated subgroup of $\mathcal{O}_K^+$ of rank $n$.
Then $H$ has a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $\omega_1,...,\omega_n $.

$\Delta (\omega_1,...,\omega_n)=\text{Det} (c_{ij})_{n \times n}  $ where $c_{ij}=\text{Trace}_{K/\mathbb{Q} }(\omega_i \omega_j) . $

**This is the part I don’t understand next.**

It says that $H \subset \mathcal{O}_K $ so each $c_{ij} $ is an integer so $\Delta (\omega_1,...,\omega_n )$ is an integer.

**My question is** why does the fact that $H \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ mean that $\text{Trace}_{K/\mathbb{Q} }(\omega_i \omega_j)$ is an integer? I could understand this if $H$ was a subring of $\mathcal{O}_K$ because then $\omega _i \omega_j $ would be an element of $H$ and then we could use the fact that $\omega_1,...,\omega_n $ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis. But $H$ is only an additive subgroup of $\mathcal{O}_K^+$. What am I missing here?

Comment: It is not necessary that $H$ is a subring, we only need that ${\cal O}_K$ is a ring because then $\omega_i\omega_j\in {\cal O}_K$, i.e. they are integral and thus so is their trace

Comment: Oh, the norm and trace of algebraic integers are integers aren’t they.

Comment: Yes, exactly, for example because they are the product/sum of the conjugates which are again integral